# SQL Query Ruby On Rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, select

I have two models `team` and `fixture`. The `fixture` model has two columns `home_team_id` and `away_team` which contain the foreign key of `team`'s primary key.

I am trying to do a select query where I can get the team name using the `home_team_id` and `away_team_id` in the fixture table.

```
class Fixture < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :away_score, :away_team_id, :home_score, :home_team_id, :result, :week
    belongs_to :team, :class_name => Team
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :form, :name
    has_many :fixtures, :class_name => Fixture, :foreign_key => :home_team_id
    has_many :fixtures, :class_name => Fixture, :foreign_key => :away_team_id
end
```

Do I need to do the SQL query in the Fixtures controller, and how can I then show it in my `fixture` view?

This is what I tried for the query but had no luck. In my fixtures show I had:

```
<p>
  <b>Home team:</b>
  <%= Team.find_by_sql("SELECT name FROM teams WHERE team.id = fixtures_home_team_id")     %>
</p>
```

Comment: You have 2 `has_many :fixtures` relations in your `Team` class, that may be a problem...

Comment: Your query says `FROM teams` but your object is named `team`.  In any case, did you get some error message?  "Had no luck" doesn't tell us much...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rewrite your models like this:

```
class Fixture < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :away_score, :away_team_id, :home_score, :home_team_id, :result, :week
  belongs_to :home_team, :class_name => 'Team'
  belongs_to :away_team, :class_name => 'Team'
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :form, :name
  has_many :home_fixtures, :class_name => 'Fixture', :foreign_key => :home_team_id
  has_many :away_fixtures, :class_name => 'Fixture', :foreign_key => :away_team_id
end
```

Now you can do this in your controller:

```
@fixture = Fixture.find(params[:id])
```

And this in your view:

```
<p>Away Team: <%= @fixture.away_team.name %></p>
<p>Home Team: <%= @fixture.home_team.name %></p>
```

Comment: Thanks great answer, worked perfect, have been over a week trying to figure it out with different sql queries I was writing my own, but your answer made it alot more simple

Comment: Do you know any good tutorials or links to any good explanations of using foreign keys within rails? Its just I havn't seen it used in examples I followed before and I presumed Rails just knew it was a foreign key by the fact it was _team_id at the end.

Comment: You almost had it correct, except you didn't specify a unique name for each association.  The association names are the only part that _must_ be specified, everything else depends on the convention used.  I would recommend starting with [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), and you can follow that up with [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association) for a better explanation.